# Keras Custom Optimizer_legacy.interfaces

Tags: python, keras

I want to make custom optimizer in keras. for this i reimplemented sgd in custom way, i mean i define class for this (MLP for binary classisification), i named my optimizer 'myopt'. Follwoing is code:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
import tensorflow as tf
import six
import copy
from six.moves import zip
from keras.utils.generic_utils import serialize_keras_object
from keras.utils.generic_utils import deserialize_keras_object
from keras.legacy import interfaces
from keras import backend as K
import numpy as np
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout
# Generate dummy data
x_train = np.random.random((1000, 20))
y_train = np.random.randint(2, size=(1000, 1))
x_test = np.random.random((100, 20))
y_test = np.random.randint(2, size=(100, 1))

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(64, input_dim=20, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

def clip_norm(g, c, n):
    if c <= 0:  # if clipnorm == 0 no need to add ops to the graph
        return g

    # tf require using a special op to multiply IndexedSliced by scalar
    if K.backend() == 'tensorflow':
        condition = n >= c
        then_expression = tf.scalar_mul(c / n, g)
        else_expression = g

        # saving the shape to avoid converting sparse tensor to dense
        if isinstance(then_expression, tf.Tensor):
            g_shape = copy.copy(then_expression.get_shape())
        elif isinstance(then_expression, tf.IndexedSlices):
            g_shape = copy.copy(then_expression.dense_shape)
        if condition.dtype != tf.bool:
            condition = tf.cast(condition, 'bool')
        g = tf.cond(condition,
                    lambda: then_expression,
                    lambda: else_expression)
        if isinstance(then_expression, tf.Tensor):
            g.set_shape(g_shape)
        elif isinstance(then_expression, tf.IndexedSlices):
            g._dense_shape = g_shape
    else:
        g = K.switch(K.greater_equal(n, c), g * c / n, g)
    return g


class Optimizer(object):
    """Abstract optimizer base class.
    Note: this is the parent class of all optimizers, not an actual optimizer
    that can be used for training models.
    All Keras optimizers support the following keyword arguments:
        clipnorm: float >= 0. Gradients will be clipped
            when their L2 norm exceeds this value.
        clipvalue: float >= 0. Gradients will be clipped
            when their absolute value exceeds this value.
    """

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        allowed_kwargs = {'clipnorm', 'clipvalue'}
        for k in kwargs:
            if k not in allowed_kwargs:
                raise TypeError('Unexpected keyword argument '
                                'passed to optimizer: ' + str(k))
        self.__dict__.update(kwargs)
        self.updates = []
        self.weights = []

    @interfaces.legacy_get_updates_support
    def get_updates(self, loss, params):
        raise NotImplementedError

    def get_gradients(self, loss, params):
        grads = K.gradients(loss, params)
        if hasattr(self, 'clipnorm') and self.clipnorm > 0:
            norm = K.sqrt(sum([K.sum(K.square(g)) for g in grads]))
            grads = [clip_norm(g, self.clipnorm, norm) for g in grads]
        if hasattr(self, 'clipvalue') and self.clipvalue > 0:
            grads = [K.clip(g, -self.clipvalue, self.clipvalue) for g in grads]
        return grads

    def set_weights(self, weights):
        """Sets the weights of the optimizer, from Numpy arrays.
        Should only be called after computing the gradients
        (otherwise the optimizer has no weights).
        # Arguments
            weights: a list of Numpy arrays. The number
                of arrays and their shape must match
                number of the dimensions of the weights
                of the optimizer (i.e. it should match the
                output of `get_weights`).
        # Raises
            ValueError: in case of incompatible weight shapes.
        """
        params = self.weights
        weight_value_tuples = []
        param_values = K.batch_get_value(params)
        for pv, p, w in zip(param_values, params, weights):
            if pv.shape != w.shape:
                raise ValueError('Optimizer weight shape ' +
                                 str(pv.shape) +
                                 ' not compatible with '
                                 'provided weight shape ' + str(w.shape))
            weight_value_tuples.append((p, w))
        K.batch_set_value(weight_value_tuples)

    def get_weights(self):
        """Returns the current value of the weights of the optimizer.
        # Returns
            A list of numpy arrays.
        """
        return K.batch_get_value(self.weights)

    def get_config(self):
        config = {}
        if hasattr(self, 'clipnorm'):
            config['clipnorm'] = self.clipnorm
        if hasattr(self, 'clipvalue'):
            config['clipvalue'] = self.clipvalue
        return config

    @classmethod
    def from_config(cls, config):
        return cls(**config)

class testsgd(Optimizer):
    """Stochastic gradient descent optimizer.
    Includes support for momentum,
    learning rate decay, and Nesterov momentum.
    # Arguments
        lr: float >= 0. Learning rate.
        momentum: float >= 0. Parameter updates momentum.
        decay: float >= 0. Learning rate decay over each update.
        nesterov: boolean. Whether to apply Nesterov momentum.
    """

    def __init__(self, lr=0.01, momentum=0., decay=0.,
                 nesterov=False, **kwargs):
        super(testsgd, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        with K.name_scope(self.__class__.__name__):
            self.iterations = K.variable(0, dtype='int64', name='iterations')
            self.lr = K.variable(lr, name='lr')
            self.momentum = K.variable(momentum, name='momentum')
            self.decay = K.variable(decay, name='decay')
        self.initial_decay = decay
        self.nesterov = nesterov

    @interfaces.legacy_get_updates_support
    def get_updates(self, loss, params):
        grads = self.get_gradients(loss, params)
        self.updates = [K.update_add(self.iterations, 1)]

        lr = self.lr
        if self.initial_decay > 0:
            lr *= (1. / (1. + self.decay * K.cast(self.iterations,
                                                  K.dtype(self.decay))))
        # momentum
        shapes = [K.int_shape(p) for p in params]
        moments = [K.zeros(shape) for shape in shapes]
        self.weights = [self.iterations] + moments
        for p, g, m in zip(params, grads, moments):
            v = self.momentum * m - lr * g  # velocity
            self.updates.append(K.update(m, v))

            if self.nesterov:
                new_p = p + self.momentum * v - lr * g
            else:
                new_p = p + v

            # Apply constraints.
            if getattr(p, 'constraint', None) is not None:
                new_p = p.constraint(new_p)

            self.updates.append(K.update(p, new_p))
        return self.updates

    def get_config(self):
        config = {'lr': float(K.get_value(self.lr)),
                  'momentum': float(K.get_value(self.momentum)),
                  'decay': float(K.get_value(self.decay)),
                  'nesterov': self.nesterov}
        base_config = super(testsgd, self).get_config()
        return dict(list(base_config.items()) + list(config.items()))


myopt = testsgd()
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer=myopt,
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x_train, y_train,
          epochs=20,
          batch_size=128)
score = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, batch_size=128)
```

Getting following error: 
 @interfaces.legacy_get_updates_support

AttributeError: module 'keras.legacy.interfaces' has no attribute 'legacy_get_updates_support'
 How to solve it.

Comment: Which version of Keras are you using?

Comment: I am using keras version 2.0.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to upgrade Keras, as version 2.0.7 is the [one](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/2.0.7/keras/legacy/interfaces.py#L657) that contains the `legacy_get_updates_support` function.

Comment: I updated Keras (2.0.8). Now getting following error:                                  ValueError: ('Could not interpret optimizer identifier:', <__main__.testsgd object at 0x7f0111606ef0>)

Comment: @Hitesh Your optimizer class should inherit from keras.optimizers.Optimizer, I am not sure why you copied the Optimizer class from Keras into your source code, that's the problem.

Comment: Actually i want to optimize CNN using my own optimization method, i am working on it, so i am trying how to make optimizer class. whether my optimizer code should be in my source code, or i have to change something in https://keras.io/optimizers/

Comment: I know what you are trying to do, but you do not have to copy the source code of the Optimizer class (note the uppercase), but your own optimizer class (what you call testsgd) has to inherit from keras.optimizers.Optimizer and only testsgd has to live in your own source code.

Comment: ok. got the point. So in my main program only testsgd should be there, and rest should be called from keras.optimizer

Comment: I still not got the solution. How can i put my own optimizer function into https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/optimizers.py    to use keras.optimizers.Optimizer.

Comment: @Hitesh I don't know what problem you have, you are not being specific, if you still have problems then make another question with all the details.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of copy-paste of keras' optimizers.py, you can just define your own class derived from Optimizer base class and put in separate .py file. For example, below is simplified version of SGD without momentum or Nesterov. Put this in a file called sgd_cust.py.

```
from keras.optimizers import Optimizer
from keras.legacy import interfaces
from keras import backend as K

class SGDCust(Optimizer):
    """Stochastic gradient descent optimizer.

    # Arguments
        lr: float >= 0. Learning rate.
    """

    def __init__(self, lr=0.01, **kwargs):
        super(SGDCust, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        with K.name_scope(self.__class__.__name__):
            self.iterations = K.variable(0, dtype='int64', name='iterations')
            self.lr = K.variable(lr, name='lr')

    @interfaces.legacy_get_updates_support
    def get_updates(self, loss, params):
        grads = self.get_gradients(loss, params)
        self.updates = [K.update_add(self.iterations, 1)]

        lr = self.lr

        shapes = [K.int_shape(p) for p in params]
        delta_ws = [K.zeros(shape) for shape in shapes]
        self.weights = [self.iterations] + delta_ws
        for p, g, delta_wi in zip(params, grads, delta_ws):
            delta_w = - lr * g  # velocity
            self.updates.append(K.update(delta_wi, delta_w))

            new_p = p + delta_w

            # Apply constraints.
            if getattr(p, 'constraint', None) is not None:
                new_p = p.constraint(new_p)

            self.updates.append(K.update(p, new_p))
        return self.updates

    def get_config(self):
        config = {'lr': float(K.get_value(self.lr))}
        base_config = super(SGDCust, self).get_config()
        return dict(list(base_config.items()) + list(config.items()))
```

Now you can use your custom optiomizer as below:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import keras
from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras.models import Sequential
from sgd_cust import SGDCust
from keras import backend as K

batch_size = 10
num_classes = 10
epochs = 5

# the data, shuffled and split between train and test sets
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
x_train = x_train.reshape(60000, 784).astype('float32') / 255
x_test = x_test_official.reshape(10000, 784).astype('float32') / 255
y_train = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train, num_classes).astype('float32')
y_test = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_test, num_classes).astype('float32')


model = Sequential()
rnd_normal_init = keras.initializers.glorot_normal()
model.add(Dense(30, activation='relu', 
                kernel_initializer=rnd_normal_init, 
                bias_initializer=rnd_normal_init, input_shape=(784,)))
model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax', 
                kernel_initializer=rnd_normal_init, 
                bias_initializer=rnd_normal_init))

model.summary()

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', #sum_squared_error
              optimizer=SGDCust(lr=0.1),
              metrics=['categorical_accuracy'])

history = model.fit(x_train, y_train,
                    batch_size=batch_size,
                    epochs=epochs,
                    verbose=2,
                    validation_data=(x_test, y_test))
score = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, verbose=0)
print('Test loss:', score[0])
print('Test accuracy:', score[1])
```